# T-Test: Variance within groups

Tags: variance, t-test, heteroscedasticity

I guess this is a very basic question, but I'm confused.

During a lecture we had a short introduction to T-Tests. Our professor referenced the following video and "explained" T-Tests using the same example: https://youtu.be/0Pd3dc1GcHc?t=3m29s

In this video, the two groups have exactly the same variance (6) and the means are 36 and 34. They calculate the t value using

[image: equation video]

What would happen if the groups had different variances? Which variance would I have to use?

Online resources often mention the following formula for the "variance within groups" for unpaired T-Tests:

[image: unpaired variance within groups]

Resulting in the final formula for t:

[image: unpaired t]

Sadly the video does not mention how many samples we are dealing with. But if we assume that both groups have the same amount of samples (n_A = n_B), the number of samples would have to be 1/3 in order to get the same "variance within groups" as in the video, which does not make sense.

Can anyone explain why or when one can simply use one of the variances of either group A or B as "variance within groups" for an unpaired T-Test?

Comment: I think your confusion is about the difference between the variance of the scores and the variance of the difference between the means. Perhaps investigate a bit further with that hint? Also you could add the self-study tag when you edit your post with your further thoughts.

Comment: Perhaps. But sadly I cannot find any explanations on what exactly was done in the YouTube video; from my understanding THEY confused the variance of the scores with the "variance within" the groups.

Comment: Perhaps Wikipedia can help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test it may be more trustworthy than YouTube